# Feedback On My Sounds

Tags: feedback

Hey All,

This is my first time posting!  I wanted to get some feedback on my sounds.  I've been designing sound for Radio for years...I got sick of typical cheesy stuff I was forced to produce with and started making my own.  Now I'm looking at taking my sound design into TV/Film.  Just a couple simple things to check out...I'd appreciate any feedback/criticism/love/coffee.

Thanks!

http://soundcloud.com/joeedwards/sound-design-sample-11-blast-2

http://soundcloud.com/joeedwards/sound-design-sample-1-jet

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SSD.

Those sound awesome.

Out of context or what these sounds would be used for I have no right to say anything critical about them.

From what I can tell there is nothing blatantly technically wrong with them, no distortion, clipping, aliasing etc.

Care to share how you created these? Info like what types of source files you used and how you processed them together? I'd love to know if you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks!  No context really...designed to be quick swooshes for radio.  Layers of white noise, some rockin' thunder/rain outside my house and some deep tones.  Oxford Reverb for smoothing, Izotope Trash to give the tail a little crackle, Waves Doppler and Oxford Inflator with a hint of Mondomod.  It's a few layers of that chain together with different pans and volume changes.  Rolled off everything above 200 Hz on one layer and pumped the volume at the pass peak to give 'em that deep punch.  A lot of layers, playing around.  It'd be could see/hear 'em in a title sequence or trailer one day.

Comment: I've done Radio Imaging mostly...promos, sweepers...all the things between songs that aren't commercials.  A lot of years in San Diego but I've done stuff all over the world.  I started out working at a recording studio/production house.  Did a lot of Radio Imaging there and I ran A&E voice sessions with Jack Perkins and some for National Geographic. Produced the audio tapes for an infomercial too.

Comment: @Burning Nice! Now, what exactly does Imaging entail? And what are sweepers?

Comment: Hard to explain. Anything about the station..."We play the most Classic Rock" or anything about a contest...car giveaways, concert tickets. Anything that isn't a commercial. Sweepers are the short pieces between songs, "The number one hit music station, Kiss FM". I've been writing, producing, voicing that stuff for years. Here's a sample of a promo and a couple custom song intros and a pack of sounds I made the other day...light airy sequences.

http://soundcloud.com/joeedwards/joe-edwards-quick-radio

http://soundcloud.com/joeedwards/sound-design-sample-pack-6